# How to add a variable on the link using javascript in laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, laravel

Is it possible to put a variable on the route url on javaScript? I need to pass the variable back to the controller. Here's my code:

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 6,
      center: {lat: 10.103523, lng: 123.640538}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    document.getElementById('go_submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });
  }

  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var waypts = [];
    var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxArray.length; i++) {
      if (checkboxArray.options[i].selected) {
        waypts.push({
          location: checkboxArray[i].value,
          stopover: true
        });
      }
    }

    directionsService.route({
      origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
      destination: document.getElementById('complete_add').value,
      waypoints: waypts,
      optimizeWaypoints: true,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions-panel');
        summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;

          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<input type="text" value="' + parseInt(route.legs[i].distance.text) + ' * 10 = " name="km" id="km">' ;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<input type="text" value="' + parseInt(route.legs[i].distance.text) * 10 + '" name="km" id="km">' ;

          var fee = '';

          $fee = parseInt(route.legs[i].distance.text) * 10;

          summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<a href="{{ url("/mode_of_payment/".' + $fee + ')}}" class="btn btn-success">CONTINUE</a>';


        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

i don't know what to do in this part.

```
summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<a href="{{ url("/mode_of_payment/".' + $fee + ')}}" class="btn btn-success">CONTINUE</a>';
```

I want to put the variable on the route.

Comment: which variable and value you want to put in route via javascript in laravel route ? also share route file code.

Comment: i've updated my question sir... that part in `summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<a href="{{ url("/mode_of_payment/".' + $fee + ')}}" class="btn btn-success">CONTINUE</a>'; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to dynamically generate php code in JavaScript loop. You could do is to save the url in a javascript variable and use that variable to loop through.

```
var fee = parseInt(route.legs[i].distance.text) * 10;

var custom_location = '{{ url("/mode_of_payment/" }}';

summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<a href='" + custom_location + "/" + fee + "' class='btn btn-success'>CONTINUE</a>";
```

Comment: why i have an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' `

Comment: Updated the code, please recheck the matching quotes

Comment: i've check it sir but still the same. and all quotes are paired.

Comment: sorry sir but i've check again the quotes i've missed 1. thank you for your answer sir it works... ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to append the root url. For this, you just declare a variable

```
root_url = "<?php echo Request::root(); ?>";
```

Then you can use this variable directly in your script code. Then your code will

```
summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<a href="'+root_url+'/mode_of_payment/'+fee+'" class="btn btn-success">CONTINUE</a>';
```

Comment: i have an error with that `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' `

Comment: this line sir `summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<a href="'+root_url+'/mode_of_payment/'+fee+'" class="btn btn-success">CONTINUE</a>';`